# How do I assign numeric node size attribute to just one column of edgelist?

Tags: r, igraph

I am plotting in igraph and having difficulty plotting with an attribute for node size.

I have tried to add size attribute data from a csv file and indicate that it only applies to one column of my edgelist (I have a separate attribute file for the other column of the edgelist). But when I attempt to plot, I get an error message.

Edgelist data:

```
el[,"org"]=as.character(el[,"org"])
el[,"office"]=as.character(el[,"office"])
el=as.matrix(el)
g=graph.edgelist(el[,1:2])
```

Attribute for size:

```
V(g)$cont_amt=as.numeric(b$cont_amt[match(V(g)$name,b$org)])
V(g)$size=V(g)$cont_amt

V(g)$size <- ifelse(V(g)$size %in% el[,1], V(g)$size, NA)
```

Attempting to plot:
`plot(g, layout=m, edge.arrow.size=.2, vertex.label.font=1,
      vertex.label.cex=.9, vertex.label.color="black")`

I have been getting this error message when I plot: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

Comment: Here's the code I've been using to plot before getting the error message: ```plot(g, layout=m, edge.arrow.size=.2, vertex.label.font=1, vertex.label.cex=.9, vertex.label.color="black")```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where is `m` coming from in your `plot` call? what happens if you just do `plot(g)`?

Comment: it's the layout ```m <- layout_with_kk(g)```

Comment: when I just do ```plot(g)``` I get the same error

Comment: I think the error is due to having `NA` in the `V(g)$size` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question relates to the comment in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284638/how-do-i-select-certain-labels-to-display-in-igraph-plot).
Consider the following minimal working example:

```
library(igraph)
a <- 1:4
b <- letters[1:4]
edgelist <- cbind(a,b)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(edgelist)
```

Here I simply generated a random graph from an edgelist.
The next step is to set the node size conditional on the apperance of the node names in the first column of the `edgelist`. The condition states that the name has to match the items in the first column. If 'yes', then increase the size to 16, if 'no' use the already specified size.

```
V(g)$size <- 8 
V(g)$size <- ifelse(test = V(g)$name %in% edgelist[,1], yes = 16, no =  V(g)$size)
```

This results in bigger sizes for the nodes from the first column of `edgelist`
[image: different sized nodes]